# Serialize ValueObject as XML

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

You would think this is a very simple question. But after lots of searching and testing I have not found a pretty solution.

As per domain driven design I created strongly typed identifier classes. Because that helps with validation and not accidentally mixing up identifiers.

So I made a simple base class like so:

```
public abstract class UIDBase<T> 
{
    private readonly T _id;

    protected UIDBase(T id)
    {
        _id = id;
    }

    public T ID
    {
        get { return _id; }
    }

    // Plus hash/equals implementation

}
```

And simple implementations like so:

```
public class SensorUID : UIDBase<string>
{
    public SensorUID(string id) : base(id)
    {
    }
}
```

And then I use it:

```
public class SomeObject
{
    public SensorUID SensorUID { get; set; }

    public FileName FileName { get; set; }
}
```

But now when I serialize it as XML, I need a default constructor (annoying). But worse, the properties are no longer serialized as attributes.

Preferable I only want to add custom Xml serialisation code to my UIDBase class. Adding attributes or implementing an interface to tell the xml serializer that these classes should be serialized as attributes. Just like string/int/long etc.

If those value types can do it, why not my own value type?

The Xml should look like:

```
<SomeObject SensorUID="X" FileName="Y"/>
```

Comment: Suggest you look at [this MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I'll look into it. I was also diving into .net source code to see how System.string pulls the same thing off. I might answer this question myself ;)

Comment: Domain entities should be persistent ignorant. Your entities are not. It's the responsibility of the repository to persist your entities correctly to XML (or the DTO that represent your domain entity).

Comment: You are absolutely right. I wanted domain entities which were oblivious to the fact that they were stored directly, to keep it somewhat clean. Preferring less code. A DTO is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, but it feels ugly:

```
public class SomeObject
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public SensorUID SensorUID { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public FileName FileName { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("SensorUID")]
    public string SensorUIDAsString
    {
        get { return SensorUID == null ? null : SensorUID.ID; }
        set { SensorUID = new SensorUID(value); }
    }

    [XmlAttribute("FileName")]
    public string FileNameAsString
    {
        get { return FileName == null ? null : FileName.ID; }
        set { FileName = new FileName(value); }
    }
}
```